# Issue with Linked List (Java applet)

Tags: java, applet

In this code, I am trying to initialize a linked list of ovals that are sent to a class to be drawn.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    oval p;
    Graphics g = this.getGraphics();
    int x, y, height, width, fill;
    ListIterator li;
    LinkedList<oval> list = new LinkedList<oval>();
    li = list.listIterator();
    x = Integer.parseInt(xfield.getText());
    y = Integer.parseInt(yfield.getText());
    height = Integer.parseInt(heightf.getText());
    width = Integer.parseInt(widthf.getText());
    list.add(new oval(x,y,height,width));
    repaint();
    while (li.hasNext()) 
    {
        p = (oval)li.next();
        p.draw(g);
    }
```

When I run this, I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(Unknown Source)
    at ovalapplet.actionPerformed(ovalapplet.java:97)
```

How can I fix this? (Line 97 is p = (oval)li.next(); if that helps.)

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the list's iterator **before** you change the state of the list, and then you use the iterator to iterate through, but now the iterator is no longer appropriate. Solution: change that order. Get the iterator only **after** adding items to the list, or use a ListIterator and add items with the ListIterator.

Other problems: you're drawing incorrectly as you should not get a Graphics object by calling `getGraphics()` on a component as this returns a short-lived object. To see what I mean, once you get your GUI working, minimize and then restore it after doing this drawing and watch your drawings disappear. Instead use a LinkedList field, change its state in your actionPerformed method, call `repaint()` and have your component's `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method (or the `paint(Graphics g)` method if this is an AWT program) do the drawing for you.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to just use Graphics g; instead of Graphics g = this.getGraphics(); but it gives me an error saying "The local variable g may not have been initialized".

Comment: @Bryan: Please re-read my recommendation. The drawing should be done within the `paint(...)` (if AWT) or `paintComponent(...)` method (if Swing, using the Graphics parameter given to the method by the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

You can rid of this by using remove() instead of calling next() where you do not want access the object while it uses by other task, which means no concurrent access.

```
while (li.hasNext()) 
{
  p = (oval)li.remove();
  p.draw(g);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the list iterator before adding any ovals to the linked list. But the iterator isn't updated when a new item is added to the linked list. That's why the exception occurs. To fix it initialize the list iterator **after** adding the new oval.